# Somers' D (contingency table) in R

Tags: r, self-study, contingency-tables, somers-d

I need to compute the Somers' D for a contingency table (choosing between R|C and C|R), but I can't find any function to do this. I know there is the `somers2` function in the `Hmisc`package, but it only works for 2x2 tables.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks!

**EDIT**:

I think I've found a solution, but I'm not sure if it's right. In [this post at StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2557863/measures-of-association-in-r-kendalls-tau-b-and-tau-c), **doug** posted a way to find the concordant and discordant pairs, where "t" is a table:

```
# number of concordant pairs 
P = function(t) {   
  r_ndx = row(t)
  c_ndx = col(t)
 sum(t * mapply(function(r, c){sum(t[(r_ndx > r) & (c_ndx > c)])},
  r = r_ndx, c = c_ndx))}

# number of discordant pairs
Q = function(t) {
  r_ndx = row(t)
  c_ndx = col(t)
  sum(t * mapply( function(r, c){
      sum(t[(r_ndx > r) & (c_ndx < c)])
  },
    r = r_ndx, c = c_ndx) )
}
```

And if I'm right, this code can be slightly modified to find the ties (for instance, in the rows):

```
TIES = function(t) {
  r_ndx = row(t)
  c_ndx = col(t)
  sum(t * mapply( function(r, c){
      sum(t[(r_ndx == r)])
  },
    r = r_ndx, c = c_ndx) )
}
```

So a function to find the Somers' D would be this one:

```
somersD = function(table, dependent="rows", digits=2){

# concordant pairs
C = function(t) {   
  r_ndx = row(t)
  c_ndx = col(t)
  sum(t * mapply(function(r, c){sum(t[(r_ndx > r) & (c_ndx > c)])},
                 r = r_ndx, c = c_ndx))
}

# discordant pais
D = function(t) {
  r_ndx = row(t)
  c_ndx = col(t)
  sum(t * mapply( function(r, c){
    sum(t[(r_ndx > r) & (c_ndx < c)])
  },
                  r = r_ndx, c = c_ndx) )
}

# ties in the dependent variable
if (dependent=="rows"){
  E = function(t) {
    r_ndx = row(t)
    c_ndx = col(t)
    sum(t * mapply( function(r, c){
      sum(t[(r_ndx == r)])
    },
                    r = r_ndx, c = c_ndx) )
  }
} else if (dependent=="cols"){
  E = function(t) {
    r_ndx = row(t)
    c_ndx = col(t)
    sum(t * mapply( function(r, c){
      sum(t[(c_ndx == c)])
    },
                    r = r_ndx, c = c_ndx) )
  }
} else { warning("'dependent' argument must be 'rows' or 'cols'") }

c = C(table)
d = D(table)
e = E(table)

somers = (c-d)/(c+d+e)

print(paste("Somers' D: ", round(somers, digits=digits)))

}
```

The problem is that I don't know if I'm doing the right thing. So would be appreciated if anyone could confirm or correct this!

Answer (score 4):

Though not very fast, the R `Hmisc` package `rcorr.cens` function will do this (`rcorr.cens(x, Surv(y))`).  If you find a very fast way to do this in R please post what you find.

Comment: I think I've found a way to do it, but I don't know if I'm right. I've edited the post to show it.